# fill rows with nan in specific columns

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, nan, fillna

I want to fill with NaNs the specific columns where the category is set to NaN

cat1 = ['a','b','c','d']

cat2 = ['drinks', 'meat', 'plant', 'salad']

for example where category_with_order is equal to NaN I want all rows of the set of columns of cat1 to be set to NaNs
same for category_without_order I want all rows of the set of columns of cat2 to be set to NaNs

[image]

expected output:
[image]

Here is my initial code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

data = {
    'category_with_order': ['a', 'b', 'c','d',np.nan],
    'category_without_order': ['plant',np.nan,'salad','meat', 'drinks'],
    'sugar': ['1',np.nan, '2', '2',np.nan],
    'salt': ['1',np.nan, '2', '1',np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
feature_array = ohe.fit_transform(df[["category_with_order","category_without_order"]]).toarray()
features_labels = ohe.categories_
feature_labels = np.hstack([i.ravel() for i in features_labels])
features = pd.DataFrame(feature_array, columns = feature_labels)
knn = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=1, add_indicator = True)
df_new = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), features.reset_index(drop=True)]
```

Comment: Why do you want to set to nan the entire row? Is it to drop this row afterward or is it for something else?

Comment: it is to drop the "NaN" columns in the header and then impute the missing values in rows for both categorical and numerical data